# Mahout LDA gives FileNotFound exception

Tags: hadoop, mahout, lda

I created my term vectors as stated [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/creating-vectors-from-text.html) like this:

```
~/Scripts/Mahout/trunk/bin/mahout seqdirectory --input /home/ben/Scripts/eipi/files --output /home/ben/Scripts/eipi/mahout_out -chunk 1
~/Scripts/Mahout/trunk/bin/mahout seq2sparse -i /home/ben/Scripts/eipi/mahout_out -o /home/ben/Scripts/eipi/termvecs -wt tf -seq
```

Then I run

```
~/Scripts/Mahout/trunk/bin/mahout lda -i /home/ben/Scripts/eipi/termvecs -o /home/ben/Scripts/eipi/lda_working -k 2 -v 100
```

and I get:

> MAHOUT-JOB: /home/ben/Scripts/Mahout/trunk/examples/target/mahout-examples-0.6-SNAPSHOT-job.jar
>   11/09/04 16:28:59 INFO common.AbstractJob: Command line arguments: {--endPhase=2147483647, --input=/home/ben/Scripts/eipi/termvecs, --maxIter=-1, --numTopics=2, --numWords=100, --output=/home/ben/Scripts/eipi/lda_working, --startPhase=0, --tempDir=temp, --topicSmoothing=-1.0}
>   11/09/04 16:29:00 INFO lda.LDADriver: LDA Iteration 1
>   11/09/04 16:29:01 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 4
>   11/09/04 16:29:01 INFO mapred.JobClient: Cleaning up the staging area file:/tmp/hadoop-ben/mapred/staging/ben692167368/.staging/job_local_0001
>   Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/ben/Scripts/eipi/termvecs/tokenized-documents/data does not exist.
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:371)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:245)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat.listStatus(SequenceFileInputFormat.java:63)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:252)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:902)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:919)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$500(JobClient.java:170)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:838)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:791)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:791)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:465)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:494)
>       at org.apache.mahout.clustering.lda.LDADriver.runIteration(LDADriver.java:426)
>       at org.apache.mahout.clustering.lda.LDADriver.run(LDADriver.java:226)
>       at org.apache.mahout.clustering.lda.LDADriver.run(LDADriver.java:174)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
>       at org.apache.mahout.clustering.lda.LDADriver.main(LDADriver.java:90)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:68)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:139)
>       at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.main(MahoutDriver.java:188)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)

It's right, that file doesn't exist. How am I supposed to create it?

Answer (score 0):

The vectors might be empty as there may be a problem in their creation. Check if your vectors are successfully created in their folders (have not a file size of 0 bytes). This error may occur if you are input folder is missing some files. In that case, these two steps will work although not create a valid output.